# Android при запуске приложения выдает следующее:

Tags: java, android, activity, adb

```
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.StartScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

Куда и в каком виде эту команду применить?
В гугле не поищешь, слишком длинный запрос.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity android:name="com.example.StartScreen">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.example.WebView" />


        <activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.Rege" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.Main2Activity">


        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity android:name="com.example.StartScreen">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.example.WebView" />


        <activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.Rege" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.Main2Activity">


        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос свой AndroidManifest.xml, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавила, спасибо за правку

Comment: Ничего никуда не надо применять, это обычный лог действий adb, он просто уведомляет Вас, что применил эту команду

Comment: У вас проблемы с запуском или просто интересно что это за команда и как её можно использовать? Об `adb` можно почитать в доках: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb и куче статей в интернетах.